# Japanese and Korean titles are blank in kodi/xbmc for FireTV

Tags: android, xbmc, amazon-fire-tv, kodi

I'm using original titles for my kodi/xbmc on amazon FireTV , however the titles are displayed blank or '' or ' '

any solution ?

Note: duplicate of question asked in more relavant forum [original question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/108419/japanese-and-korean-titles-are-blank-in-kodi-xbmc-for-firetv)